# Porque se dispara el evento 'animationend' antes de tiempo?

Tags: javascript, eventos, animación

Estoy intentado hacer que al terminar la animacion salte una funcion, en este caso la funcion 'mensaje()', y utilice el evento 'animationend', pero no funciona como deberia.

Porque si se supone que 'webkitAnimationEnd' o 'animationend' es un evento que se dispara al finalizar la animación, lo hace incluso antes de empezar la animación?

```js
let imagen = document.getElementById('imagen');
imagen.addEventListener('webkitAnimationEnd', mensaje(), false);

function mensaje() {
  alert('hola');
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

img {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 20px;
  animation: anim1 1s linear;
}

@keyframes anim1 {
  0% {
    right: 0%;
  }
  100% {
    right: 1000px;
  }
}
```

```html
<img src="Sources/background.jpg" id="imagen">
<a href="#" onclick="play()">Iniciar</a>
```

Comment: ¿La respuesta solucionó tu problema? Por favor no olvides marcarla como aceptada si tu problema fue resuelto. Puedes hacerlo marcando el ✓ en la parte izquierda de la respuesta (se pondrá verde, ganarás 2 puntos de reputación y podrías acceder a [nuevos privilegios](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges)). ¡Mira [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) si tienes alguna duda!

Answer (score 1):

Por que, al momento de colgarte al evento, estas llamando a la función en lugar de pasarla como parámetro.

#### Solución:

Solo tenes que sacar los paréntesis.

```
imagen.addEventListener('webkitAnimationEnd', mensaje, false);
//                                                   ^ aca
```

**Demo**:

```js
let imagen = document.getElementById('imagen');
imagen.addEventListener('webkitAnimationEnd', mensaje, false);

function mensaje() {
  alert('hola');
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

img {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 20px;
  animation: anim1 1s linear;
}

@keyframes anim1 {
  0% {
    right: 0%;
  }
  100% {
    right: 1000px;
  }
}
```

```html
<img src="Sources/background.jpg" id="imagen">
<a href="#" onclick="play()">Iniciar</a>
```